# Как пометить/снять все флажки в списке?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть список с CheckBox'ами, как по нажатию по кнопке пометить/снять пометку всех CheckBox'ов?

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите вопросы понятным языком. Чем лучше оформлен вопрос - тем быстрее будет получен ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде ничего сложного - привязки, команды...

Пусть у меня есть такая VM, представляющая один элемент списка:

```
class ItemVm : Vm
{
    string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => Set(ref name, value, nameof(Name));
    }

    bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => isChecked;
        set => Set(ref isChecked, value, nameof(IsChecked));
    }
}
```

А главная VM содержит коллекцию таких элементов и команды чтобы помечать или снимать пометки со всех элементов:

```
class MainVM : Vm
{
    public List<ItemVm> Items { get; }
    public ICommand CheckAllCommand { get; }
    public ICommand UncheckAllCommand { get; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Items = new List<ItemVm>
        {
            new ItemVm { Name = "Молоко" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Творог" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Сметана" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Кефир" },
            new ItemVm { Name = "Сыр" }
        };
        CheckAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            _ => Items.ForEach(item => item.IsChecked = true));
        UncheckAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(
            _ => Items.ForEach(item => item.IsChecked = false));
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <UniformGrid Grid.Row="1" Rows="1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <Button Content="Check all" Margin="0,0,2.5,0"
                Command="{Binding CheckAllCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Uncheck all" Margin="2.5,0,0,0"
                Command="{Binding UncheckAllCommand}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Grid>
```

[image: checkAll.gif]

Если вы хотите вместо двух кнопок использовать один CkeckBox, то можно обойтись одной командой, принимающей параметр:

```
CheckAllCommand = new DelegateCommand(
    o => Items.ForEach(item => item.IsChecked = (bool)o));
```

тогда в команду надо просто передать параметр - текущее состояние флажка:

```
<CheckBox Content="Check all"
          Command="{Binding CheckAllCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

Но я не стал делать этот вариант, т.к. вы не описали нужно ли как-то этому общему флажку реагировать на установку/снятие флажков в списке вручную по одному.